# calling mprapi.dll functions in .net

Tags: c#, .net, unmanaged

I am trying to call native api in c# .net. Can anyone please help me translating the code below into C# call? I would be really thankful.

```
dwResult = ::MprAdminMIBServerConnect( pwcComputerName.GetText(), &hMibServer );

dwResult = ::MprAdminServerGetInfo( hMibServer, 0, (LPBYTE*)&pServerBuf );

// I want to read the below variables as string
pInObjectEntry->Put(L"rastotalportstoconnectto", pServerBuf->dwTotalPorts );
pInObjectEntry->Put(L"rasportsinuse", pServerBuf->dwPortsInUse );
```

---

Here is the sample code, can anyone please tell me how can I read values of dwTotalPorts and dwPortsInUse?

```
  class RASCollector
    {
        [DllImport("mprapi.dll", SetLastError = false)]
        public static extern UInt32 MprAdminMIBServerConnect([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpwsServerName, out IntPtr phMibServer);

        [DllImport("mprapi.dll", SetLastError = false)]
        public static extern UInt32 MprAdminServerGetInfo(IntPtr phMprServer, UInt32 dwLevel, out byte[] pServerBuf);

        public void Run()
        {
            IntPtr hMibServer = new IntPtr();
            UInt32 result;

            result = MprAdminMIBServerConnect("localhost", out hMibServer);

            byte[] pServerBuf;

            result = MprAdminServerGetInfo(hMibServer, 0, out pServerBuf);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is done through using InterOP.
You need to import each function like this:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("mprapi.dll", SetLastError = false)]
public static extern UInt32 MprAdminMIBServerConnect([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpwsServerName, out IntPtr phMibServer);
```

The datatypes defined in MSDN library should be converted to their C# datatype counterparts. You should check this article for more information on it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ac7ay120.aspx

For more information on marshalling complex data structures and pointers in C#:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsvc/archive/2009/02/18/marshalling-complicated-structures-using-pinvoke.aspx

Comment: what about other function. Is it look ok?

`[DllImport("mprapi.dll", SetLastError = false)]
public static extern UInt32 MprAdminServerGetInfo(IntPtr phMprServer, UInt32 dwLevel, out byte[] pServerBuf);`